# .NET Adding Custom Http Headers to Web Service Proxy throws errors

Tags: .net, service, asmx

I need to attach custom header to my Web service client.
For this purpose I created partial class for the SoapHttpClientProtocol class that was generated when I added the web reference.  However, I am receiving runtime error when my custom headers are attached.  Everything works fine if custom headers are not attached 
(when I comment the code that attaches headers).
However if custom headers are added then I receive following error during runtime:
Client found response content type of 'text/html; charset=utf-8', but expected 'text/xml'.
Any ideas?

So here is the sample code:

```
 public partial class SMARTSWS : System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol 
{
    private NameValueCollection _customHeaders = new NameValueCollection();

    protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(System.Uri Uri)
    {
        // Add authentication cookie to the 
        // this object CookieContainer
        SmartsIVRSecurityManager.SetAuthToken(this);

        // Set Custom Headers
        SetCustomHeaders();

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(Uri);
        for (int i = 0; i <= _customHeaders.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            req.Headers.Add(_customHeaders.Keys[i], _customHeaders.GetValues(i).GetValue(0).ToString());
        }
        return req;
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Set Custom Headers
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="smToken"></param>
    public void SetCustomHeaders()
    {
        _customHeaders.Add("Version", "1.0");
        _customHeaders.Add("OnBehalfOf", String.Empty);
        _customHeaders.Add("Role", "1");
        _customHeaders.Add("EndPoint", "001");
        _customHeaders.Add("ServiceId", "001");
        _customHeaders.Add("DateTime", String.Empty);
        _customHeaders.Add("ClientApplication", "SmartsIVRService");
        _customHeaders.Add("TraceWebMethod", "false");
        _customHeaders.Add("ClientTouchPoint", "SmartsIVRService");
        _customHeaders.Add("ChannelInfo", "ChannelInfo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you see a response of type "text/html", it is usually an error page trying to tell you what's wrong. Use Fiddler or something to see what the error page is trying to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

If you break just after you fetch the request from your base class, what does the webrequest content type say?

Is it set to text/html or text/xml? I'm wondering if your casting call is changing the type.

Comment: HttpWebRequest.ContentType is null